# Flutter: collapsing app bar with pinned tabBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How add build collapsing app bar with pinned tabBar in Flutter like in this GIF 
[image: GIF]

Answer (score 7):

I managed to build it like so

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                title: Text('Test'),
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab( text: "Call"),
                    Tab( text: "Message"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Text("Item $index");
              })),
              Container(child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Text("Item $index");
                  })),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Man, accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SilverAppBar

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 150.0,
  floating:true,
  pinned: true,
  flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
    title: Text('Available seats'),
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
      tooltip: 'Add new entry',
      onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
        ),
      ]
    )
```

References

- [SliverAppBar Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)
- [SliverAppBar Widget of the week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9C5KMJKluE)

Comment: I know slivvers but im not able to collapse the app bar and pinned to tab bar like in the gif

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `TabBarView` seperate from the `SliverAppBar`.

Make it look continuous by setting `SliverAppBar`'s `elevation` to 0 and use `shadow` or `elevation` for the `TabBarView`, whatever you prefer.