# How to integrate SliverAppBar within CustomScrollView along with a SliverFixedExtentList, and Scaffold with scrollable tabs?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The goal is to design an UI that looks like Twitter's profile page, where you can check the user's profile(block A), then you have a tab bar(block B), and unlimited scrollable tabviews(block C). The tab bar should act like a `SliverAppBar`, which can be "pinned" when you scroll up to the end of block A.

I can build a `SliverAppBar` within a `CustomScrollView` with the profile part (block A) as its `background` attribute, and set `expandedHeight` bigger to review profile part. However in this solution, I don't know how to make the `SliverFixedExtentList` part into a srollable tabviews and how to make the SliverAppBar a TabBar.

Codes of this solution:

```
  CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: 450.0,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
          background: Profile(), // Profile class show's the users name, picture, and bio, etc.
          title: Text('Demo'),
        ),
      ),
      SliverFixedExtentList(
        itemExtent: 50.0,
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
              child: Text('List Item $index'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Another solution: if I start with building tab bar and tab views along with a scaffold, then I don't know how to integrate a `SliverAppBar` as the appbar to build block A.

The question is how to integrate those widgets, a SliverAppBar, a Scaffold, and scrollable tabs togather?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "integrate"? what does your code look like now?

Comment: By integrate I mean combine their features to achieve the designing goal. I've just added the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to build it with help from [Flutter: collapsing app bar with pinned tabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771800/flutter-collapsing-app-bar-with-pinned-tabbar).

```
      Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
              return [
                SliverAppBar(
                  floating: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "Posts"),
                      Tab(text: "Likes"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  expandedHeight: 450,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                    background: Profile(),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 40,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                        child: Text('List Item $index'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 40,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                        child: Text('List Item $index'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Before scrolling:

[image: Before scrolling]

After scrolling:

[image: After scrolling]